# How can I represent basis points in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, formatting, devexpress

I have a DevExpress `dxe:TextEdit` control with `EditValueType="{x:Type system:Decimal}"`. I would like this TextEdit control to display and accept values that are 10,000 times the actual value. E.g., if someone enters 15, it should save the actual value as .0015. And if the value in the viewmodel is .0015, it should display 15.

I am new to WPF and I am not sure the best way to accomplish this. It seems like I can't do it with format strings, but I could be wrong. A value converter seems like overkill. I also thought about modifying the setter on my model object, but I don't think that would work, and it seems sort of hack-y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked with DevExpress a while ago.

As far as I can remember, you can create your own TextEdit class. (Derive from TextEditBase or even go further and derive from BaseEdit).

However, talking about over-killing, I think this is a much greater over-kill than just creating a converter, which will be a really good solution IMHO.

Comment: Okay, so converter is the standard practice here for WPF? Honestly difficult for me to tell.

Comment: The idea of converter is to convert your real data, to the visual data you want to show the user. You example is the classic use for it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the get/set functions to accomplish this. Perfect way of using them to translate presentation format to/from storage format.

Comment: Do you know how that would work with EF? Like, when EF populates my model object from the database, will it not call the setter, and divide the stored database value by 10,000?